# How to pass string in post request body in postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have an POST API end point, i.e.

```
[Route("api/{parameter1}/employee")]
[HttpPost]
public Employee RegisterEmployee(string parameter1, [FromBody] string parameter2)
```

Now, I want to hit this API from postman.

My request URL is:

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/api/parameter1/employee
```

And the body is:

[image]

So, in this way I am getting: 415 Unsupported Media Type error.

If I try other ways then i am able to hit the API, **but parameter2 is always coming as null**.

So, how should I pass the parameter2 value in postman?

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit about the specification of endpoint you are hitting, the request that you send(code -> curl) also the response you get vs expected.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, The issue i have mentioned is: I am not getting any values in parameter2 when hitting the API. It doesn't matter what you are getting in response from the API.

Comment: You could try to bind the first parameter with `[FromRoute]` to make it explicit that it is not from body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting content type to `application/json`. JSON String inputs thankfully capture as strings in ASP.NET Core.

[image]

Alternatively, you could read the body string from the request stream:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
{  
    return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass simple String from Postman

```
<route url="/V1/test/" method="POST">
    <service class="App\CustomRestApi\Api\TestInterface" method="testData"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

[image]

Interface

```
 namespace App\CustomRestApi\Api;
 interface TestInterface
{
 /**
  * Return request
  *
  * @param string $customData
  * @return mixed
  */
 public function testData(string $customData);}
```

---

Model

```
namespace App\CustomRestApi\Model;
use App\CustomRestApi\Api\TestInterface;
class Test implements TestInterface
{
 /**
  * @param string $customData
  * @return string
  */
 public function testData(string $customData)
 {
    return $customData;
 }
 }
```

---

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="App\CustomRestApi\Api\TestInterface"
            type="App\CustomRestApi\Model\Test" />
 </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You now have to specify where the string/int is coming from. i.e. in your controller method specify:  `GetUser([FromBody] string username)` then in postman ensure your are sending the string as JSON